# Angular8 PrimeNG dropdown in reactive forms - initial value

Tags: angular, select, dropdown, primeng

Using:
Angular: "8.2.11"
primeng: "8.1.1"

**How to initialize the value in select field when opening form in the primeng dialog?**

I tried to initialize through FormGroup:

```js
this.form = new FormGroup({
  selectedValue: new FormControl("some value"),
});
```

Also I tried to initialize through setValue method:

```js
this.form.controls.selectedValue.setValue = "some value";
```

this methods no changes the placeholder’s value (i.e., it is not visible visually), but sets the value (hidden - i.e. when sending form data, the value is really set)

Comment: Can you post your html code?

Comment: What do options that you provide to the primeng dropdown look like? I just tried both ways of passing the initial value (initialize in FormGroup and setValue - setValue is a method) and they both worked.

Comment: I found a solution - need to pass not a value of type string, but an object. (an object from the array - [options] = "objectFromThisArray")

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution - need to pass not a value of type string, but an object. (an object from the array - `[options] = "objectFromThisArray"`)